# Error with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, json

I have a problem with jQuery call web method.

follows the entire code:

```
$ ("# Button1"). Click (function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault (); 
                ValidaUser ("Sads", "Sads"); 
            }); 

            ValidaUser function (nomeUser, passus) { 

                var obj = {}; obj.sUserName = 'p'; obj.UserPass = 'test'; 


                $. Ajax ({ 
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "Default.aspx / ValidateUser" 
                    date: JSON.stringify (obj) 
                    / / Date: '{"sUserName": "' + + nomeUser'"}', 
                    contentType: "application / json, charset = utf-8" 
                    dataType: "json", 
                    success: function (msg) { 
                        if (msg.d) 
                            $ ("# Message"). Hide ("clip"); 
                        else 
                            $ ("# Message"). Show ("bounce") 
                        $ ("# LabelMensagem.") Text ("User not found."); 


                    } 
                    error: function () { 
                        alert ("An unexpected error has occurred during processing."); 
                    } 
                });


       [WebMethod()]
        public static bool ValidateUser(string sUserName, string UserPass)
        {
            if (sUserName == UserPass)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
```

and this return `Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'sUserName'.`

Comment: Are all those extra spaces in your code, or is it a transcription error in the question?

Comment: I second that, what's with all the whitespace in questionable locations?  I assume that the actual URL is "Default.aspx/ValidateUser", and that the `Date:` line is commented out?

Answer (score 0):

change date to data in your Ajax method call.

Answer (score 0):

You have 'ortographic' errors (spaces, case, commas, missing equals). Your code should be:

```
$("#Button1").click(function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault (); 
      ValidaUser ("Sads", "Sads"); 
}); 

ValidaUser = function (nomeUser, passus) { 
    var obj = {}; obj.sUserName = 'p'; obj.UserPass = 'test'; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "Default.aspx / ValidateUser" 
        data: JSON.stringify (obj),
        // data: '{"sUserName": "' + + nomeUser'"}', 
        contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (msg) { 
            if (msg.d) 
                $("#Message").hide("clip"); 
            else 
                $("#Message").show("bounce") 
            $ ("#LabelMensagem").text("User not found."); 
        } 
        error: function () { 
            alert ("An unexpected error has occurred during processing."); 
        } 
    });
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers